# How does the 'Jobs' option in Oracle SQL Developer work?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, job-scheduling

How to schedule a Job which needs to run every hour in Oracle?

This job should be able to execute  3 Oracle DB select statements.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235

Comment: I don't have admin access on the DB, so wanted to know if anything can be done using the "Jobs" option in the Oracle SQL Developer..

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-18.1/RPTUG/sql-developer-concepts-usage.htm#GUID-4590F0E8-45E2-41D6-BF56-2E7220499E5A) "*SQL Developer provides a graphical interface for using the DBMS_SCHEDULER PL/SQL package to work with Oracle Scheduler objects*"

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer does not run any jobs - the jobs always run inside the Oracle database. Which client you use to define the jobs is irrelevant. You **have** to have the privilege to use `dbms_scheduler`. And because a scheduler jobs runs on the server without a GUI, it's completely unclear what you want those three SELECT statements to do. Where should the results be displayed?

Comment: Well, I wanted to create 3 temporary tables in one of the schema and wanted to refresh it every hour, but now since I don't have DBA access, guess a simpler way is do it through a cron job. Thanks for the above information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple demo that should get you started

Three tables

```
SQL> create table t1 as select * from user_objects;

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 as select * from user_objects where object_id > 100;

Table created.

SQL> create table t3 as select * from all_objects where owner = 'SCOTT';

Table created.
```

Now we write some simple PLSQL to do the refresh of them

```
SQL> begin
  2     delete t1;
  3     delete t2;
  4     delete t3;
  5     insert into t1 select * from user_objects;
  6     insert into t2 select * from user_objects where object_id > 100;
  7     insert into t3 select * from all_objects where owner = 'SCOTT';
  8     commit;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

and if we are happy that this works, we simply wrap into a scheduler job to run every hour

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_anon_block varchar2(500) :=
  3      q'{begin
  4           delete t1;
  5           delete t2;
  6           delete t3;
  7           insert into t1 select * from user_objects;
  8           insert into t2 select * from user_objects where object_id > 100;
  9           insert into t3 select * from all_objects where owner = 'SCOTT';
 10           commit;
 11         end;}';
 12  begin
 13      dbms_scheduler.create_job (
 14         job_name           =>  'MY_REFRESH_JOB',
 15         job_type           =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
 16         job_action         =>  l_anon_block,
 17         start_date         =>  sysdate,
 18         repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=HOURLY',
 19         enabled            =>  true,
 20         comments           =>  'Hourly Refresh');
 21  end;
 22  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Connor, I can access dbms_scheduler with just a read access to that schema ?

Comment: The ability to use the scheduler has its own privilege, namely, "CREATE JOB".  You'll need your DBA to give you access